# Selenium is not performing Click Action on the Radio Button

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, test-automation-framework, cucumber

Issue: I am trying to perform a click on a radio Button but it is not working it just bypass the step and perform the next step doesn't even give me any error message

[image]

*Intention is to click on refund Radio Button

Selenium Code: `

```
@Given("^User select Refund with Cash on Case Summary Page$")
public void user_select_Refund_with_Cash_on_Case_Summary_Page() throws Throwable {
WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'col-md-12']/solvup-component-field/div/solvup-radio-type/div/div[2]/label/input"));
Actions ob = new Actions(driver);
ob.moveToElement(radio);
ob.click(radio);
Action action = ob.build();
action.perform();`
```

HTML:

```
<solvup-component _ngcontent-c2="" _nghost-c4="" id="" class=""><!----><fieldset _ngcontent-c4="" class="no-border">
        <legend _ngcontent-c4="" class="">Please select the remedy to be applied:</legend>

        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row component-content">
            <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-12">
                <!----><solvup-component-field _ngcontent-c4="" _nghost-c7=""><div _ngcontent-c7="">

  <!---->
  <!----><solvup-radio-type _ngcontent-c7="" _nghost-c9=""><div _ngcontent-c9="" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">

    <solvup-label _ngcontent-c9="" _nghost-c33=""><label _ngcontent-c33="" class="control-label">
     <!----> 
</label>
<solvup-tooltip _ngcontent-c33="" _nghost-c36=""><!---->
</solvup-tooltip>
</solvup-label>

  <!----><div _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio">
      <label _ngcontent-c9="" class="">
          <input _ngcontent-c9="" type="radio" id="replace_refund_override_radio" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
          Replace
      </label>

  </div><div _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio">
      <label _ngcontent-c9="" class="">
          <input _ngcontent-c9="" type="radio" id="replace_refund_override_radio" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
          Refund
      </label>

  </div>
</div>
<solvup-hint-text _ngcontent-c9="" _nghost-c34=""><!----><p _ngcontent-c34="" class="help-block"></p>
</solvup-hint-text>
<solvup-validation-messages _ngcontent-c9="" _nghost-c35=""><!----><div _ngcontent-c35="">
    <!---->
    <!---->
</div>



<!---->

</solvup-validation-messages>


</solvup-radio-type>
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->








  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
</div>

</solvup-component-field><solvup-component-field _ngcontent-c4="" _nghost-c7=""><div _ngcontent-c7="">

  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!----><solvup-hidden-field _ngcontent-c7="" _nghost-c23=""><div _ngcontent-c23="" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">
    <input _ngcontent-c23="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="hidden" value="0" name="jbhifi_replace_refund_override_component.replace_outcome_hidden" id="Request_replace_outcome_hidden">
</div></solvup-hidden-field>
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->








  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
</div>

</solvup-component-field><solvup-component-field _ngcontent-c4="" _nghost-c7=""><div _ngcontent-c7="">

  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!----><solvup-hidden-field _ngcontent-c7="" _nghost-c23=""><div _ngcontent-c23="" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">
    <input _ngcontent-c23="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="hidden" value="" name="jbhifi_replace_refund_override_component.insurer_ext_liability_hidden" id="Request_insurer_ext_liability_hidden">
</div></solvup-hidden-field>
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->








  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
</div>

</solvup-component-field>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!---->

</fieldset>






</solvup-component>
```

Tried Explicit Wait , Actions , Click Does anyone have any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Verify the checkbox is Selected or not by using the `isSelected()` method.

Then use the below code,

```
WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Refund')]"));
```

or

`WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='replace_refund_override_radio']")[2]`);

Use `thread.sleep` before locating the element

Hope this will work.

Comment: I used this method as well with my xpath it says True. I also used this xpath but it gives an error with xpath - unable to locate element

Comment: updated the answer. Try this